# NoMethodError Omniauth Facebook in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I got some problem with OmniAuth FaceBook login into my webapp.
Tell me please, what should i edit to fix this error? Check the code.

Error in the browser:

> undefined method `to_a' for "Name Surname":String

User.rb:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      x = auth.info.name.to_a
      user.name = x[0]
      user.surname = x[1]
      user.login = auth.info.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]

    end
  end
```

Omniauth_callback_controller.rb :

```
def facebook
    if request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email.blank?
      redirect_to "/users/auth/facebook?auth_type=rerequest&scope=email"
    end
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      if(@user.surname.nil?)
        redirect_to new_profile_path
      else
        redirect_to my_profile_path
      end
    end
  end
```

devise.rb :

```
config.omniauth :facebook, '*********', '*********', {:client_options => {:ssl => {:verify => false}}}
```

Comment: Facebook auth can provide `auth.info.first_name` and `auth.info.last_name` separately, it will be more reliable in case users have more than two names to access them this way. See this other SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090322/get-first-name-and-last-name-fields-from-facebook-omniauth).

Answer (score 0):

name is a string and you are trying to convert it to array

```
x = auth.info.name.to_a
```

use `split` instead

```
x = auth.info.name.split
#=> ['Name', 'Surname']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of OmniAuth first_name and last_name:

Update your devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, '*********', '*********', info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name', {:client_options => {:ssl => {:verify => false}}}
```

and your user.rb:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|

      user.name = auth.info.first_name
      user.surname = auth.info.last_name
      user.login = auth.info.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]

    end
  end
```

Comment: When i pasted 'info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name' , RubyMine yell me about syntax error and underline this part of code

Comment: It is correct as per the omniauth documentation: `config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'  ` as shown [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview). Have you tried to run it?

Comment: Now, when i hit Login with facebook...it redirect me back to my localhost but now url look like this : http://localhost:3000/#_=_

Comment: So it takes you back to a non auth protected page? Can you share your User controller?  The #_-_ character is added by Facebook to the callback URL. Do you have the omni_ath callbacks set correctly in your routes.rb? ie: `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }`

Comment: Yes i have omniauth in routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

your user.rb should be like this

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do  |user|
      x = auth.info.name.split
      if x.count > 1
        user.name = x[0]
        user.surname = x[1]
      else
        user.name = x[0]
      end 
      user.login = auth.info.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
end
```

But I would suggest to store in a single field, because name can be of more than two words so it would become difficult to identify name and surname.

[this link should also help](http://get%20first_name%20and%20last_name%20fields%20from%20facebook%20omniauth)